# Resolving subdomains to addresses

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, iis-7, http

I'm looking at a corporate web site (theServer.theDomain.com) having an address that is correctly resolved if I simply type the subdomain by itself:

```
ping theServer
```

But if I try to reach that web site in a browser...

```
http://theServer
```

...it fails with a 404 not found.  HTTP access succeeds only if I enter the FQDN.  The first thing that comes to mind is IIS 7 configuration.  Perhaps a proper change there would allow simply the subdomain to be accepted (suggestions?).  But besides a potential ambiguous name (a conflict with the same subdomain in another domain root) what other problems might I encounter to get the result I'm looking for?  For example, perhaps a gateway is configured to route HTTP traffic as if it is external traffic.  In that case, a subdomain alone would never work.

I'm looking for a checklist of items to consider to make this work.  This is only for use within the corporate intranet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like IIS isn't configured to handle requests for "theServer", but *is* configured to handle "theServer.theDomain.com". Presumably what is then happening is that IIS is serving up the default page instead of the specific virtual host for "theServer.theDomain.com".

I'm not sure about IIS 7, but on earlier versions you can go to the IIS configuration, edit the properties for the website, go to the 'Web Site' tab, click 'Advanced...', and add an entry to the 'Multiple identities for this website' list for just "theServer". It should then handle it correctly.

Comment: +1.  In IIS 7, it's the "Edit Bindings" setting on the right side when the site is selected.

Comment: Cheers Shane... I've not had chance to play with IIS 7 yet!